# Intentionally Pause JSP loading

Tags: jsp

Is there any way to intentionally pause the loading of a JSP page?

I'm trying the following...

```
<%
try
{
    String strWait = request.getParameter("wait");
    int iWait = 0;
    if (strWait != null || !strWait.isEmpty())
    {
       iWait = Integer.getInteger(strWait);
    }

    if (iWait > 0)
    {
       Thread.sleep(iWait);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {}
%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    ... etc....
```

Text to fill out the silly stack overflow requirement for more text and less code...

Comment: clarify your question. You want to pause the execution and what?

Comment: Just pause the execution then continue after the `iWait` period. I'm testing a tool which gives page response time and want to intentionally delay the page for X milliseconds so that the tool triggers an alert.

Comment: Vote 4 close: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. Also this is a "dump code and ask what's wrong here" question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout function of javascript.

In your case just pass your 'wait' value to a javascript function like below

```
functionToRunFirst();
setTimeout(function() {
    // rest of code here
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

For any others... This workflow works. My problem was the `Integer.getInteger(strWait)` call.

This should have read `Integer.parseInt(strWait)`